# regex to filter php array by conditional existence of value

Tags: php, regex, array-filter

I have have a php array

```
    $arr[0] = "something/somethingelse/anotherval";
    $arr[1] = "something/!somevar/anotherval";
    $arr[3] = "something/!notcorrect/anotherval";
    $arr[4] = "something/somethingelse/_MyVal";
    $arr[5] = "something/_MyVal/anotherval";
    $arr[6] = "something/_AnotherNotCorrect/anotherval";
```

I'm using array_filter to filter the array by certain criteria...

```
    $f = array_filter(array_keys($arr), function ($k){ 
    return ( strpos($k, 'something/') !== false ); });
```

This returns all my vals where the term something/ is matched... I'd like to be able to say IF we encounter a ![something here] or a _[something here] then we need to make sure that the [something here] matches either $afterExcl or $afterUnderscore. If we didn't encounter a ! or _ then just check the strpos($k, 'something/') !== false check...

(notice that the ! and _ portions may or may not be at the end of val string)

I'm assuming this is regex, but I've always struggled to build them.

CLARIFICATION
Thanks. Clarification though, the ! or _ sequence may not be the next directory after something/, it may three or four more steps in. AND, I'll be providing a $afterExcl or $afterUnderscore value which will designate approved values. Basically the client is using ! and _ to denote "regions" ie. 
something/images/!Canada 
something/videos/tutorials/!Canada or 
something/images/!USA or 
something/images/!Mexico OR last 
something/images/All

then I'd specify

$afterExcl=Canada

My filter would return

something/images/!Canada 
something/videos/tutorials/!Canada 
something/images/All

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$f = array_filter(array_keys($arr), function ($k){ 
    return preg_match('~something/(?![_!])~', $k); });
```

The negative lookahead `(?!...)` checks if the slash isn't followed by a `!` or a `_`.

Note that `preg_match` returns 1 if found or 0 if not. If you want to return `true` or `false` you can do it with the ternary operator:

```
return preg_match('~something/(?![_!])~', $k) ? true : false;
```

**an other way**:

If you use `strpos`, I assume that the string you describe as `'something/'` is a fixed string `$str`, in other words you know the length of this strings. Since `strpos` returns the position `$pos` in the string of the occurence, you can easily check if at the position `$pos + strlen($str)` there is either an exclamation mark or an underscore. *(you could, for example, extract this next character and check if it is in the array `array('!', '_')`)*

Comment: Thanks. Clarification though, the ! or _ sequence may not be the next directory after something/, it may three or four more steps in. AND, I'll be providing a  $afterExcl or $afterUnderscore value which will designate approved values. Basically the client is using ! and _ to denote "regions" ie. something/images/!Canada something/videos/tutorials/!Canada or something/images/!USA or something/images/!Mexico OR last something/images/All then I'd specify $afterExcl=Canada My filter would return something/images/!Canada  something/videos/tutorials/!Canada something/images/All